# how to efficiently perform bounded geo query?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Any suggestions for how to efficiently perform bounded geo query? caching?

**Background**

I am using google maps + marker clusterer, and every time user changes bounds I query the backend. I would like to make this more efficient.

**Options**

1. No Caching - on bounds change -> query with new bounds -> update all markers
2. Caching on bounds change -> divide the bounds into quadkeys -> check the quadkey cache -> query for markers using quadkey not in cache -> add new quadkey markers to the map

Suggestions please?